# Switching from Broker-side compression to producer compression

Tags: apache-kafka, compression, kafka-producer-api

I have the situation where my producers currently do not use compression. The topic is configured with `compression.type=lz4`.

Say that I wanted to, in the future, switch this configuration to be on the producer side, so that `compression.type=producer` and my producers use e.g. `lz4`.

My questions are:

1. Are there any special considerations for this scenario?
2. What if I were to choose another compression algorithm on the producer side down the road, e.g. `zstd`? Does Kafka retain the required metadata for this to be possible, or would I need to reprocess my topics so that a single compression algorithm would be used during its lifetime?